# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.Profile>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<Models.Profile>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I implemented the sorting, filtering, paging on my web page by following the tutorial in the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.2

The sorting and paging are working fine but I had an issue on the search feature. I got the error "Cannot implicitly convert tyoe 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable'". Can someone help me please. Thanks in advance

I have here my Model.Profile

```
public partial class Profile
{
    public Profile()
    {
        Assessment = new HashSet<Assessment>();

    }

    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName ("Profile Name")]
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }
    public int PerspectiveId { get; set; }
    public int InfluenceLevelId { get; set; }
    public int OwnershipLevelId { get; set; }
    public string Interviewer { get; set; }
    [DisplayName ("Date Interviewed")]
    public DateTime? DateInterviewed { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Created By")]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Created Date")]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Modified By")]
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Modifed Date")]
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Industry Industry { get; set; }
    [DisplayName ("Influence Level")]
    public virtual InfluenceLevel InfluenceLevel { get; set; }
    [DisplayName ("Ownership Level")]
    public virtual OwnershipLevel OwnershipLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual Perspective Perspective { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Assessment> Assessment { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my code on my Controller that's throwing the error

```cs
{
    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchData;

    var profile = _context.Profile
        .Include (p => p.Industry)
        .Include (p => p.InfluenceLevel)
        .Include (p => p.OwnershipLevel)
        .Include (p => p.Perspective)
        .Include (p => p.Role)
        .OrderByDescending (p => p.ProfileName);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (searchData)) {

        profile = profile.Where (p =>
            p.ProfileName.Contains (searchData)); //Here is the error

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an `IOrderedQueryable` type of `profile` at first and then you assign an `IQueryable` type of date  `profile.Where (p =>p.ProfileName.Contains (searchData));` to it.

Try to use below code to set `profile` as `IQueryable`:

```
var profile = from p in _context.Profile
              select p;

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (searchData)) {

    profile = profile
       .Include (p => p.Industry)
       .Include (p => p.InfluenceLevel)
       .Include (p => p.OwnershipLevel)
       .Include (p => p.Perspective)
       .Include (p => p.Role)
       .OrderByDescending (p => p.ProfileName)
       .Where (p =>p.ProfileName.Contains (searchData));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable profile is already declared as IOrderedQueryable and you try to assign a IQueryable.

What happens if you try:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (searchData)) {

    var profile2 = profile.Where (p =>
        p.ProfileName.Contains (searchData)); //Here is the error

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a simple solution.  When using LINQ, you can use the `.ToList()` method.  So, for your code:

```
var profile = _context.Profile
    .Include (p => p.Industry)
    .Include (p => p.InfluenceLevel)
    .Include (p => p.OwnershipLevel)
    .Include (p => p.Perspective)
    .Include (p => p.Role)
    .OrderByDescending (p => p.ProfileName)
    .ToList(); // add here

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (searchData)) {

    profile = profile.Where (p =>
        p.ProfileName.Contains (searchData)).ToList(); // add here

}
```

I've created a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yfiJVu) to show you an example I just wrote up.  It is working as expected.

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Xing Zou!

Yesterday I also tried to add the IQueryable on my data set as seen below and it works. When I saw your answer, I tried it and it's also working. Thanks for the help, the 2 implementations work :)

```
        IQueryable<Profile> profile = _context.Profile
            .Include(p => p.Industry)
            .Include(p => p.InfluenceLevel)
            .Include(p => p.OwnershipLevel)
            .Include(p => p.Perspective)
            .Include(p => p.Role)
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProfileName);


        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchData))
        {

            profile = profile.Where(p => p.ProfileName.Contains(searchData));

        }
```